# Move an IntelliJ IDEA project to Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm starting work on java project. The application has no GUI and does not use any JavaEE technology (I think it is important to say). Currently I'm the only active developer. The people who did write the application before me used IDEA, in fact all project development is done in IDEA.

I'm a long term Eclipse user. I'm used to it, I know most of its traits and am comfortable in it. And Eclipse is most powerful in pure JavaSE projects that have no web interface.
Currently I'm struggling to cope with IDEA - don't know shortcuts, don't know how to configure it, so on. IDEA's Mac OS version is not that well done as Eclipse's.

The people that chose IDEA just said Eclipse didn't feel right (when I first started using Eclipse I had the same impression, then after a few months loved it). They also write the opening curly brace on a new line which really bugs me. So I don't see any valid arguments against Eclipse.

Should I move to Eclipse or give IDEA some more time?

Comment: After a year I think that staying with Idea was a bad idea. I never got used to it, had to work with both IDEs. The trouble of going to Eclipse would have been worth it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give IntelliJ more time.

Your style concerns can be fixed by setting the code style.  You can reformat the entire project at the push of a button, although I'd think carefully about it.

I used Eclipse for four years and loved it.  I was grateful to have something so good while working for an employer that would not by tools.

Six years ago I was given IntelliJ and I've never looked back.

"Most powerful"?  Eclipse?  Not even close.  Give IntelliJ more time.

Comment: What do you think about IDEA on MacOS X? I think it has some issues but I haven't used it enough. Also what version of IDEA are you talking about? I was asking about the comunnity (free) version

Comment: I don't use Mac, so I can't say.  I use a paid version of IntelliJ 10.x, the latest one.

Answer (score 3):

I am a long time IntelliJ user and really love it. I would also advise to give it more time. You might also want to install the [Key Promoter](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=1003) plugin to help you discover the really nice keyboard shortcuts that it has. It will help you become very productive with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should stay with the IDE that fits your needs and makes you feel more confortable.

We are now in 2017 and both IDEs provide more or less the same functionalities. There was a time when IntelliJ was a lot more powerful than eclipse, but now there are no significant diferences between them.

So it is a matter of taste.